# Code Does Not Return Rows

Tags: php, html, joomla, html-table, joomla3.0

I am attempting to write the query results to a html table.  The sql is valid but for some reason the table only displays the header row.  This should return roughly 15 rows.  What is incorrect with the syntax, and how should I modify so that it writes the data to the table?

```
    <?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    $option = array(); //prevent problems

    $option['driver']   = 'mssql';            
    $option['host']     = 'XXX.XXX.XX.XX';    
    $option['user']     = 'user';       
    $option['password'] = 'pass';   
    $option['database'] = 'database';      
    $option['prefix']   = '';             

    $db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
    $result = $db->getQuery(true);
    $result->select($db->quoteName(array('Host', 'Location', 'NumberOfPlayersAttending', 'NumberOfPlayersCompeting')));
    $result->from($db->quoteName('[EventInfo')); 
    $db->setQuery($result); 
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>NumberOfPlayersAttending</th>
            <th>NumberOfPlayersCompeting</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach( $options as $option ) 
            { 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Host']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['Location']); ?> </td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['NumberOfPlayersAttending']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print_r($option['NumberOfPlayersCompeting']); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            } 
        ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**EDIT**
Also altering the syntax to `foreach( $results as $option )` only produces a header row, still no data being returned.

**EDIT 2**
This is the data that `$results` is returning

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Host] => Red Robin [Location] => Omaha, Neb [NumberOfPlayersAttending] => 25 [NumberOfPlayersCompeting] => 13 ) )
```

Comment: You're assigning the results to `$results`, but trying to iterate through `$options`.

Comment: and print_r is for arrays. $option['Host'] is a string ? "echo" the variable.

Comment: @aynber - changing the syntax to foreach( $results as $option )  produces a table with header.  No data.

Comment: @TopCheese - they are string values.  I tried to use `<td><?php echo $option['Host']; ?></td>` but same result as before - only a table with no data

Comment: what's in the $results variable ? print the result out for us ? @MichaelMormon

Comment: @TopCheese - how would I print it?

Comment: var_dump($results) or print_r($results) in your php file right under $results = $db->loadObjectList(); then copy paste the result of the print here. @MichaelMormon

Comment: @TopCheese - see my edit for the values that `print_R($results)` returns

Comment: @MichaelMormon $option is an object, $option->Host to get the Host value. Same process for other values you want to do $class->property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through `$results` instead of `$options`, as this is the variable that contains your query output.

**Update**

Also the HTML won't print new rows for each result.

to fix your code, access the results of your query using object operators, as that is what is returned:

```
   <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>NumberOfPlayersAttending</th>
            <th>NumberOfPlayersCompeting</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach( $results as $option ) { 
              print "<tr>";
              print "<td>".$option->Host."</td>";
              print "<td>".$option->Location."</td>";
              print "<td>".$option->NumberOfPlayersAttending."</td>";
              print "<td>".$option->NumberOfPlayersCompeting."</td>";
              print "</tr>";
            } 
            ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

loadObjectList, a method of the class JDatabase returns objects for each row parsed. As you can see [here](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JDatabase::loadObjectList):

> Method to get an array of the result set rows from the database query
>   where each row is an object.

Comment: Changing the syntax to foreach( $results as $option )  - just prints a outputs a table with header only.  No data.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing "option" seems likely to be a problem.
Changing your loop the way you have doesn't fix that.

Either change the name of your array with the database params in it or the foreach line.  "foreach $results as $result" with the corresponding change within the loop would be smarter.

You're right, it seems wrong that it doesn't work the way you've done it, except your names are the same so they could be causing the problem